# Как очистить поле ввода при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно очистить 2 поля ввода (ru_word и eng_word) после нажатия на кнопку. Через ".delete(0, END)" не получается. Что мне делать ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pickle

words = {
"hi" : "привет",
"no" : "нет",
"yes" : "да",
}

try:
    words = pickle.load(open("words.txt", "rb"))
except FileNotFoundError:
    pickle.dump(words, open("words.txt", "wb"))
    words = pickle.load(open("words.txt", "rb"))

def translater():
    user_word = txt.get()
if user_word in words:
    lbl.config(text = words[user_word])

for name in words:
    if user_word in words[name]:
        lbl.config(text = name)

def append_word():
    global words
    en = eng_word.get()
    ru = ru_word.get()

    words[en] = ru
    pickle.dump(words, open("words.txt", "wb"))
    print(words)


window = Tk()
window.title("Android")
window.geometry('300x600')

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)


tab_control.add(tab1, text='Поиск')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Словарь')
tab_control.add(tab3, text='Добавить слово')

txt = Entry(tab1, width=30)
txt.pack()
btn = Button(tab1, text = "Искать", bg="orange", command = translater)
btn.pack()
lbl = Label(tab1, text = "Перевод")
lbl.pack()

ru_word = Entry(tab3, width=30, text = "")
ru_word.pack()
eng_word = Entry(tab3, width=30, text = "")
eng_word.pack()
btn2 = Button(tab3, text = "Добавить слово", command = append_word)
btn2.pack()


tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: В этом коде не используется метод `.delete(0, END)`. Удалять можно с помощью него, но т.к. в коде он не используется, то нельзя сказать, что вы делали не так.

Answer (score 1):

Всё работает

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pickle

words = {
"hi" : "привет",
"no" : "нет",
"yes" : "да",
}

try:
    words = pickle.load(open("words.txt", "rb"))
except FileNotFoundError:
    pickle.dump(words, open("words.txt", "wb"))
    words = pickle.load(open("words.txt", "rb"))

def translater():
    user_word = txt.get()
    if user_word in words:
        lbl.config(text = words[user_word])

        for name in words:
            if user_word in words[name]:
                lbl.config(text = name)

def append_word():
    global words
    en = eng_word.get()
    ru = ru_word.get()

    ru_word.delete(0, tk.END)
    eng_word.delete(0, tk.END)

    words[en] = ru
    pickle.dump(words, open("words.txt", "wb"))
    print(words)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Android")
window.geometry('300x600')

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)


tab_control.add(tab1, text='Поиск')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Словарь')
tab_control.add(tab3, text='Добавить слово')

txt = tk.Entry(tab1, width=30)
txt.pack()
btn = tk.Button(tab1, text = "Искать", bg="orange", command = translater)
btn.pack()
lbl = tk.Label(tab1, text = "Перевод")
lbl.pack()

ru_word = tk.Entry(tab3, width=30, text = "")
ru_word.pack()
eng_word = tk.Entry(tab3, width=30, text = "")
eng_word.pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(tab3, text = "Добавить слово", command = append_word)
btn2.pack()


tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

window.mainloop()
```